# How to reference the blazor.server.js file when publishing to an nginx server

Tags: c#, nginx, blazor-server-side

I have published the default blazor server application that visual studio creates on an nginx server, however I can't find a way to reference the _framework/blazor.server.js file, this is my nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name blazor.local;

    location ~* \.(css|js|styles\.css|server\.js|lib|png|ttf|otf|woff)$ {
        root html/blazor/wwwroot;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The setup works fine and it can reference the css that it couldn't but there is no way to reference the _framework/blazor.server.js ?????

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I try to find an answer to that too. But no one seems to care. Or even provide a working configuration. The important thing is. Running the app in VS works fine and everything is like expected.
I noticed too that _framework/blazor.server.js is nowhere to be found.
What I can add is that

```
location ~* \.(css|js|styles\.css|server\.js|lib|png|ttf|otf|woff)$ {
    root html/blazor/wwwroot;
}
```

can be removed since it is handled my the dotnet webserver.
However I started with the problem that static files give an 404 error but after changing the configuration multiple times and ending up with the same configuration (I am sure of it) that don't worked the first time. Static files are now handled correctly.
Whats left is the fact that SignalR does not seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Some resources like `_framework/blazor.server.js` or in case of Blazor 8 `_framework/blazor.web.js` do not even get included in the publish output. Therefore you must exclude `wwwroot/_framework` from getting served by nginx and let Kestrel handle that location:

```
location ^~ /_framework/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```